# Saving/retrieving usernames and passwords in java text file

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to save a list of usernames and passwords the user enters in one text file. It should look something like this:

    `admin#admin
    bob#123456
    username#pass`
(theses are supposed to be on new lines)
The part before the sharp(#) is the username and the after being the password.

This is what I have so far:

```
String path;
private boolean append_to_file = false;

public void writeToFile(String username, String password) throw IOExection{
     FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
     PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);

     print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", username + "#" + password);
     print_line.close();
}
```

I know that people are going to say use a database, but i need to do it this way for this assingment. And when I want to retrieve a username and the corresponding password how will i do so?

Comment: What if I name my user `Mr#numbersign`? Or the password is `kcc#51h`?

Comment: I just need this to be as basic as possible, I am not implementing that part yet.

Comment: So the actual problem is loading or what?

Comment: And if loading is the problem. Why did you post the method for the writing part?

Comment: well loading is the main problem, i put this part up to see if i was entering the data correctly.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Does the writing part work? What did you try to load them?

Comment: What is the actual question here?  Is something not working? Or are you expecting somebody to finish the assignment for you?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I am not asking anyone to do the work for me. I am having trouble on where to start when reading from the file. So i just need something to start with like what functions...

Comment: Why would you save passwords in the clear in a textfile? That defeats the whole purpose of passwords.... hint: they're supposed to be secret. Even as an exercise it does not make sense. Ah well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void writeToFile(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
    out.write(username + "#" + password);
    out.newLine();
    out.close();
}
```